# Web server integration in Windows application

Tags: c#, .net, nginx

I am developing a Windows application using the .NET framework. I am exploring the best ways to integrate a web server in my application that listens to localhost:8080 (or whatever port). I do not want to compromise on the security of the user so I would like to use some library or existing web server application that is secure and does not have vulnerabilities.

So I rounded myself to 2 ways - 
1) Using a popular web-server like nginx or apache - and invoking it through the application (and running it as a process with `CreateNoWindow = true;`).
2) Using a web server written in C# or C++ like  WebServer.

What would be the best way to do it? I am open to more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this 3 ways in .NET

1. If it's a web service or Data service your can use the ServiceHost to host your own endpoints
2. IIS Express is probably the most robust and "proper" solution, unfortunately it's still in beta. You can get it by downloading Webmatrix. http://www.asp.net/WebMatrix
3. The source code for the webserver embedded in Visual studio is available, it's called Cassini. I've used it on a few projects. It's available as source or even packaged:

http://code.google.com/p/cassini/

http://ultidev.com/Products/Cassini/

Comment: Cassini seems it can be what I need. But is there any source of Documentation available for it? The code is not at all commented.

Comment: I had the same issue I'm afraid. It's not to bad if you just step through it. The main thing you need to change is that it usualy only binds to the internal ip address (127.0.0.1) but it's quite easy to fix, it's a matter of just changing an enum value.